# How to get the Uri path from a ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, android-volley, crop, wallpaper

I am trying to create a wallpaper application. All images will come from internet.

Before of set as background, I need to crop the image. And for this, I am using an API named AndroidImageCropper. This API need of a URI object to execute the crop.

How can I get the Uri from ImageView? Because my image is from internet. The image is not on drawable folder. I am confusing. Maybe you guys can help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NetworkImageView imageView;
private Uri mCropImageUri;
public static final String URL_PHOTO = "http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/iron-man-wallpaper-42-610x1084.jpg";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

    // Singleton for Volley API, Load image from internet
    ImageLoader loader = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
    loader.get(URL_PHOTO, ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, R.drawable.temp_picture, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

    imageView.setImageUrl(URL_PHOTO, loader);

    // Put the image on URI object
    // #################################
    // ###    mCropImageUri =  <--   ###
    // #################################

}

// Action for my button
public void cropImage(View view) {
    // API to crop an image
    CropImage.activity(mCropImageUri)
            .start(this);
}
```

}

Do you have any suggestion to me?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't post a picture of your code. If you can read the rules for [ask] a good question then you can [edit] your question to include the actual code

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for remind me.

Comment: Thanks better now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're using **Volley**? I'm not very familiar with Volley, both just some of my thoughts.

After image is downloaded to Android device, try to find the absolute path of the file and use **android.net.Uri.fromFile** to get a uri from the image.

Or else, can you use **Bitmap** object directly, instead of an uri.

---

OK, after some investigation, I think you have two solutions.

1. Using volley to download image as file, without using **ImageLoader**. In this way it's easy to get file uri of the image.
2. For **Android-Image-Cropper**, you can use Activity or use View(refer [here](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)). You can get the Bitmap object of the image in method **onLoadingComplete** of **ImageLoadingListener**. Then use **com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView** to crop the image.

Comment: Yes, i am using Volley. If you have an another suggestion of API, I will be glad too. All suggestion is welcome. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. You are awesome. I did what you said and worked perfectly.

Comment: @DanJhonatan Mark the answer as accepted, so that it can help others.